# All circuits show low voltage / lights flickering

Tags: electrical, neutral, voltage

Problem started two weeks ago and was first noticed when our microwave sounded very low-power. Later, a power tool was used in the home and it blew a surge protector on a different circuit. Three circuit breakers were tripped. We had the utility company out and they said that everything was fine on their side and to get an electrician to inspect the home. Since then, I've had two electricians out and the utility company back two more times...

All signs point to a bad external neutral, though the lines into the home from the poles have been replaced, and continuity checks have been performed between the meter base and inside the service panel. Both electricians are stumped. All circuits in the home are impacted.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If all circuits, then the problem should be somewhere from the panel to outside.  This does not help much but should limit the problem area.  If just a few circuits, the area gets larger.  If the problem seems to come and go, it is possible there is a wire broken inside of the insulation.  This is harder to find since the wire needs to move/bend to find it as it is being tested.  Much more common in extension cords that get bent a lot, than household wires.  A bad neutral is easy to test, you do not get equal voltage on different 120 volt circuits.

Comment: **Voltage readings**: Easiest at a 4-wire dryer receptacle, but can do any pair of 120V receptacles that are on the two different legs. Hot-Neutral, Hot-ground, Hot-hot (if you have a dryer receptacle to test it). Get a baseline with as much stuff *off* as possible. Then see if it changes when you turn on large 120V loads and/or when you turn on large 240V loads (e.g., oven).